# When .NET assemblies are compiled, what are the classes that have x__ in their names?

Tags: c#, .net

For example:

- `StudentRegistrationService<>c__DisplayClass1`
- `` <>f__AnonymousType56`2 ``
- `DocShareClassification<GetErrors>d__2`

I'm fairly certain that `StudentRegistrationService<>c__DisplayClass1` is a closure, and `` <>f__AnonymousType56`2 `` was generated when an anonymous type was specified, but I've never seen the `d__` class before.  Are there any more than just these?

Comment: Why would this matter? I mean, listing internal undocumented things that might change in any future release or service pack doesn't bring much value as we shouldn't rely on them anyways.

Comment: Curiosity.  I'm seeing them in PartCover test coverage results, and wondering which (if any) are significant enough to include in coverage reports.

Comment: @Jeremy, I would exclude any method which is tagged with the `CompilerGenerated` attribute.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508828 - see my answer to that for details.

Comment: Thanks Eric, your answer there is exactly what I was looking for but couldn't figure what to search on

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to learn about VS debugger 'magic names'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508828/where-to-learn-about-vs-debugger-magic-names)

Answer (score 6):

These are classes which are generated by the C# compiler in order to support at least the following features

- Closures / Anonymous Method expressions
- Anonymous types
- Iterators

The `d__2` one is likely an iterator helping class.

Answer (score 1):

That are at compile time generated classes created by using anonymous types

Answer (score 0):

IIRC it is classes generated for iterator blocks. However you should make any assumptions about these names or rely on them - it is implementation details and may be changed in any time