# What is this Type in .NET (Reflection)

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

What is this Type in .NET? I am using reflection to get a list of all the classes and this one turns up.

What is it? where does it come from? How is the name DisplayClass1 chosen? I search the sources and didnt see anything. What does the `<>` mean? what does the `c__` mean? is there reference?

[image]

Comment: I [blogged about this](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/delegates-vs-function-pointers-part-4-c.html).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's almost certainly a class generated by the compiler due to a lambda expression or anonymous method. For example, consider this code:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int x = 10;
        Func<int, int> foo = y => y + x;
        Console.WriteLine(foo(x));
    }
}
```

That gets compiled into:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ExtraClass extra = new ExtraClass();
        extra.x = 10;

        Func<int, int> foo = extra.DelegateMethod;
        Console.WriteLine(foo(x));
    }

    private class ExtraClass
    {
        public int x;

        public int DelegateMethod(int y)
        {
            return y + x;
        }
    }
}
```

... except using `<>c_displayClass1` as the name instead of `ExtraClass`. This is an *unspeakable name* in that it isn't valid C# - which means the C# compiler knows for sure that it won't appear in your own code and clash with its choice.

The exact manner of compiling anonymous functions is implementation-specific, of course - as is the choice of name for the extra class.

The compiler also generates extra classes for iterator blocks and (in C# 5) async methods and delegates.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Accepted (when the time comes)

Comment: Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: @Vinnyq12: Beyond "don't use lambda expressions which capture variables other than `this`"?

Comment: @JonSkeet An API requires an Expression as a parameter. When I explicitly set the parameter it is accepted but if I dynamically build up the expression an "ExtraClass" is created and it is no longer accepted :( API is SharePoint.

Comment: @Vinnyq12: Sounds like you should ask a separate question with lots more detail.

Comment: @JonSkeet I did but no love was given. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459073/dynamically-create-params-for-sharepoint-client-object-model-expression-includew

Answer (score 23):

Jon is of course correct. I've provided a "decoder ring" for figuring out what the various compiler-generate type names mean here:

[Where to learn about VS debugger 'magic names'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508828/where-to-learn-about-vs-debugger-magic-names/2509524#2509524)

The names are quite long and we sometimes get complaints that we're bulking up the size of metadata as a result. We might change the name generation rules to address this concern at any time in the future. **It is therefore very important that you not write code that takes advantage of knowledge of this compiler implementation detail.**