# How to distingush compiler-generated classes from user classes in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, compiler-construction

I have a piece of code in my program that distinguishes compiler-generated classes by checking whether they contain "DisplayClass" in its type name.
upon reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402491/what-is-this-type-in-net-reflection/6403431#6403431), I think I need a better way. How to distingush compiler-generated classes from user classes in .NET?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check classes for attribute `CompilerGenerated` to distinguish compiler generated classes from other

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilergeneratedattribute.aspx

In reflector those *Display* classes can be seen like this:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass1
{..}
```

Comment: Note: if you autogenerate code yourself, use the `GenerateCodeAttribute`, instead of the `CompilerGeneratedAttribute`, as [explained by David Kean in this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2007/04/27/correct-usage-of-the-compilergeneratedattribute-and-the-generatedcodeattribute.aspx).

Comment: The article is no longer available but thanks for the hint 

Answer (score 7):

This answer really helped me out! Here's the code I needed to add to check a `Type` for the `CompilerGeneratedAttribute` as Valentin Kuzub mentioned:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

//...

bool IsCompilerGenerated(Type t)
{
    var attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(t, typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute));
    return attr != null;
}
```