# Distinguish closure classes

Tags: c#, lambda, mono, closures, portability

I need a reliable way to distinguish compiler generated closure objects.

I found a viable solution using CompilerGeneratedAttribute: [How to distingush compiler-generated classes from user classes in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418779/how-to-distingush-compiler-generated-classes-from-user-classes-in-net/15665679#15665679)
It turns out i can use CompilerGeneratedAttribute.

Here is my current code:

```
static bool IsClosure(Type t)
{
    return IsCompilerGenerated(t) && !t.Name.Contains("AnonymousType");
}

static bool IsCompilerGenerated(Type t)
{
    return Attribute.IsDefined(t, typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false);
}

void Main()
{
    var site = new Model();

    var propertyExpression = (Expression<Func<string>>)(() => site.Prop);
    var memberAccess = (MemberExpression)propertyExpression.Body;
    var modelExpression = (MemberExpression)memberAccess.Expression;
    var closureExpression = (ConstantExpression)modelExpression.Expression;
    var closureType = closureExpression.Value.GetType();

    Console.WriteLine("Type: {0} Is closure: {1}", closureType, IsClosure(closureType));

    var anonymous = new { x = 0 };

    Console.WriteLine("Type: {0} Is closure: {1}", anonymous.GetType(), IsClosure(anonymous.GetType()));
}

class Model
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
Type: MyClass+<>c__DisplayClass0_0 Is closure: True
Type: <>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.Int32] Is closure: False
```

As i understand from and [Anonymous Types - Are there any distingushing characteristics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315146/anonymous-types-are-there-any-distingushing-characteristics/315186#315186) about anonymous objects, is that the problem is similar for compiler generated closure types, and distinguishing characteristics are essentially an implementation detail. Is that the case?

Is there a more reliable method to distinguish closure objects, considering portability to mono and future versions of .NET?

Comment: It's almost always wrong to put yourself in a position where you'd *care* if a type is a closure type or not.

Comment: @Servy If you are interested why it's necessary - a big legacy framework which makes use of expressions in form () => Prop (used in an instance method of a model, and possibly () => site.Prop (used outside of the mode), which are then processed with an expression visitor to a form of (model) => Prop, that's why i need to dig inside the expression for a FieldExpression->ConstantExpression->Value which holds an example model in closure.

Comment: Then you very clearly don't need to know this.  You don't need to know if that type is a closure type.  Just traverse the expression tree all the way to the top, rather than until you get to a closure type.  Whether the body uses a closure, or some other means of accomplishing the goal, shouldn't matter to you in that context; you should be doing the same thing *regardless of whether a closure is used or not*.

Comment: The same Constant is generated for `this`, that's why i can't. And `this` is implied to be the model, which i then need to promote to a parameter with PrameterExpression.

Comment: Which you can do just fine without needing to know or care if that top level object is compiler generated or not.

Comment: In case of `this`, the said Constant.Value holds the model itself (`this`), but in case of a closure, the model is a FieldExpression(ConstantExpression) and i need to extract that with fieldInfo.GetValue.

Comment: Closing over `this` *creates a closure*, so you have a closure in both cases.  So clearly you have some means of determining which expression represents the model beyond just whether or not the object is a closure object; use that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92281/discussion-between-george-polevoy-and-servy).