# C# Reflection Type.Name consists solely of generic brackets on non-generic class

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a class in an assembly I am reflecting through:

```
public class Example
{
    public List<int> things;
}
```

When reflecting over the assembly and grabbing type.Name:

```
foreach(var type in typeof(Example).Assembly.GetTypes())
    var hold = type.Name;
```

What is stored in the variable `hold` is just generic brackets, `<>`, and the type.FullName is `Example+<>`. What is going on? This works with every other class in the assembly. This class does have two partial files, neither define it to be generic though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6418779/34397

Comment: In `.Name` of a type, the angles `<>` are not related to generic types. A generic type would be something like ``"SomeClass`3[TOne, TTwo, TThree]"`` if you use `.ToString()`, but only ``"SomeClass`3"`` with `.Name`.

Comment: SLaks, thank you, I was unable to find that question in my initial search because I did not know I was looking for a compiler-generated class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These types are generated by the compiler to help make your code work.

They come from lambdas, iterators, or anonymous types.

Comment: To avoid getting this type when doing my assembly reflection I checked if the type had the CompilerGeneratedAttribute. Thanks for your help

Comment: To see something about the naming of these C# compiler-generated types, see [this answer in another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2509524/1336654). Of course there is no guarantee this will not change in the future.