# Empty <> before C# class name

Tags: c#, decompiling

I need to repair C# code that was decompiled on with .NET 4. Unfortunately, on my workstation there is only .NET 3.5 installed and that might be the reason why the following code  won't compile:

```
ReportPage.<>c__DisplayClass26 <>c__DisplayClass = new ReportPage.<>c__DisplayClass26();
```

What <> construct means here?
There are no c__DisplayClass26 strings anywhere in the code except this line. This might mean that this name is constructed from some metainformation that was missed during decompilation.

Comment: Obtain the source. In most cases if you are decompiling with a view to recompiling, it *probably* isn't your code and you *probably* shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: And at least find a C# 4.0! The `Visual Studio Express` is free :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C# compiler sometime has to introduce variables/fields/classes. When he has to do it, he prepends them `<>` to their name, so there won't be a name collision (with the C# compiler, it's illegal to name something with those two characters). This happens for example for auto generated properties, the `yield` keyword, lambda & anonymous functions/delegates, the new `async` keyword (the one that is introduced in the Async CTP and that will probably be present in C# 5.0)...

Now... It's strange that you have the `c__DisplayClass26` only there. Perhaps your decompiler wasn't up to the par. Try looking at the code with `IlSpy`.

Look at this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/pTRVyVdp (it isn't mine). There is an example with `c__DisplayClass`. In the first half of the text there is the "original" code, in the second half the decompile one. You see, in this case it's used for a closure. At lines 32/33 there is a `[CompilerGenerated] private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass2`. You should have it too in your code.

Mmmh... IlSpy is a little too much good :-) Often it's able to reconstruct the "original" code from the `CompilerGenerated` code.

Answer (score 4):

xanatos is correct; you are looking at a class that was automatically generated to implement closure semantics.

My handy guide to interpreting the magic names that the C# compiler generates when it has to make something on your behalf is here:

[Where to learn about VS debugger 'magic names'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508828/where-to-learn-about-vs-debugger-magic-names/2509524#2509524)

But again let me emphasize that you should not rely upon this; this is for entertainment purposes only. We reserve the right to change this scheme at any time.

Answer (score 2):

This was a compiler-generated class.  It was most likely created from an anonymous delegate or lambda inside of a method of the `ReportPage` class.

You should be able to see where this is used in your decompiled code, and try to figure out what it's doing to back it out.