# How do I read c# method names converted ToString()

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, diagnostics

Often C# debug messages and stack traces contain method names that look similar to the following:

```
XGI.Dialogs.XgiMainMenuDialog+<>c__DisplayClass16_0
```

I always struggle to read these strings. What is the "+<>" after my class name? What is "DisplayClass"; I have no such method or class in my code.

Any advice on how to interpret these method name strings?

Comment: Someone asked the same question. It may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401860/what-does-displayclass-name-mean-when-calling-lambda

Comment: They are classes that the compiler generates. The `<>` is part of the actual name of the class. (So the name is `<>c__DisplayClass16_0`) That way, there will never be a naming conflict.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. Makes sense now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14092456/2594485