# What does the symbol <> mean in MSIL?

Tags: c#, .net, cil

I have this code after decompile

```
    SampleClass sampleClass;
    SampleClass <>g__initLocal0;
    int y;
    sampleClass = null;
Label_0018:
    try
    {
        <>g__initLocal0 = new SampleClass();
        <>g__initLocal0.X = 5;
        <>g__initLocal0.Y = 10;
        sampleClass = <>g__initLocal0;
        goto Label_003A;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    Label_0035:
        goto Label_003A;
    }
Label_003A:
    y = sampleClass.Y;
```

I don't know what mean operator/symbol <> before some operations. Does somebody know?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a compiler generated name - the `<>` characters are legal for identifiers in IL, but not in C#. So, the compiler knows it can generate names containing such characters without any chance that the name will conflict with a name you've used in your code.

In this particular case, `<>g__initLocal0` is a new variable that has been introduced to hold a newly constructed instance of a class which is being initialized using [initializer syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx). The original code was:

```
sampleClass = new SampleClass() { X = 5, Y = 10};
```

It's introduced to avoid `sampleClass` being observed with the partially constructed instance - after `new SampleClass()` has executed but before the assignments to `X` and `Y` occur. I.e. if `Y = 10` throws an exception, it ensures that `sampleClass` remains `null` and not a new `SampleClass` with `X` set to 5 and some unknown value for `Y`.

Comment: For information about how exactly are these names formed, see [this answer from Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2509524/41071).