# What does this notation involving angle brackets mean?

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, async-await, notation

I'm reading [Async in C# 5.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449337163), and the section on the compiler transform contains this snippet:

```
public Task<int> AlexsMethod()
{
    <AlexsMethod>d__0 stateMachine = new <AlexsMethod>d__0();
    stateMachine.<>4__this = this;
    stateMachine.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<int>.Create();
    stateMachine.<>1__state = -1;
    stateMachine.<>t__builder.Start<<AlexsMethod>d__0>(ref stateMachine);
    return stateMachine.<>t__builder.Task;
}
```

There are two pieces of notation that are new to me. The first is `<AlexsMethod>d__0`. The second is `stateMachine.<>4__this`. Neither works when I try them myself, so I suspect it's for use by the compiler only. But I'm having trouble searching for more information on what is intended by this notation.

Comment: Someone made a post on SO once showing a lot of what the C# compiler (at the time - subject to change) made - all of the random little characters (e.g. the `4` in `4__this`) you see have an implicit meaning. Edit: here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508828/where-to-learn-about-vs-debugger-magic-names

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike the brackets marking generics (e.g. `Task<int>`), they don't have special meaning. They're just what the compiler generates - identifiers that are valid in IL, but not in C#.

Comment: And the code which generates the names is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Symbols/Synthesized/GeneratedNames.cs) (borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2509524/774575))

Answer (score 0):

When you use lambda expression, lambda expression is a anonymous method. But compiler need to give it a name, so these methods are generated by compiler, it is not readable for human.