# Detecting closures with cecil

Tags: c#, cil, mono.cecil

I have code to detect when an exception is created inside of a method like so:

```
foreach (var instr in body.Instructions)
{
    if (instr.OpCode.Code == Code.Newobj)
    {
        var methRef = (Mono.Cecil.MethodReference)instr.Operand;
        var type = Type.GetType(methRef.DeclaringType.FullName);
        if (typeof(System.Exception).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

full code [here](https://github.com/yaur/SpellUnit/blob/master/SpellUnit.ExceptionLiteralsExtractor/ExceptionLiteralsExtractor.cs).

So far this is working well for straight forward code, but in the case where I'm dealing with a closure it obviously won't work because the exception is inside of a method on the object generated for the closure, not in the method that I am currently testing.  The exception in:

```
    private static  int DataAccessMethod(int value)
    {
        int r = 0;
        System.Threading.ManualResetEvent evt = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);
        var workItem = System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((_) =>
            {
                if (r == 0)
                {
                    throw new System.InvalidOperationException("I canr spell.");
                }
                r = value * value;
                evt.Set();
            });
        evt.WaitOne();
        return r;
    }
```

for instance will go undetected.  My question is:

Is there anyway to detect that the operand to newobj is referring to a closure type?

Comment: Closures do not exist at the IL level. You should be able to heuristically recognize closure classes generated by the popular compilers. I believe they have distinctive names and structure. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @usr I was hoping to not have to go down that road since its brittle, but if the classes are otherwise indistinguishable at the IL level I guess there isn't much choice.  Thats a yes btw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @usr noted in comments closures are just normal classes, they doesn't exist distinctly in IL. Only difference is you've not created it; compiler did it for you.

I believe you should be looking at unique compiler generated names to find them. [EricLippert describes naming conventions followed by compiler here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2509524/2530848), Do note that it is subject to change in future versions of compiler.

Also after coming to the conclusion that the `Type` is a closure you can verify that using `CompilerGenerated` attribute.