# Assembly.GetTypes() returns strange type names e.g. "<>c"

Tags: c#, .net

When using `Assembly.GetTypes()` I get types that have `Type.Name` that begin with `<>c....`.

I tried to google if this is anonymous types or something else. But cannot get a really good answer.

Is there a property on Type that indicate what these types are? I do not like having to do `if(type.Name.StartsWith("<>"))`

Comment: those types are generic

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Types that have a `<>c` to them are not generic, they're compiler generated classes.

Comment: You can find an explanation of some of the compiler-generated type naming conventions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2509524/55847

Answer (score 41, accepted):

These are compiler generated display classes. You can distinguish them by looking for the [`CompilerGeneratedAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilergeneratedattribute.aspx):

```
var attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(type, typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute));
```

Comment: I have a question. after an instance of a class (let's say Foo) was removed from the memory, a memory profiler shows that a type called "Foo+<>c" is still hanged in the memroy. Is this a memory leak or it's okay to have a such? Thanks in advance?

Comment: @Abdulkarim There is a difference between an instance of a class and the type instance itself. A `Type` instance is also loaded in memory per type you use, and the CLR doesn't unload them (it only does so if you shut down the entire AppDomain). i.e. `Assembly.GetType()` return an instance of type `Type`.

Answer (score 12):

They're compiler generated types, which would include anonymous types, but also the implementations of `IEnumerable<T>`, `IEnumerator<T>`, `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` that are produced by `yield` and the state-machine structures produced by `await`.

They will have the `CompilerGeneratedAttribute`.

You describe the names as "strange" and they are deliberately such. They are all names that are valid .NET names, but not valid in common .NET languages, particularly C# and VB.NET. This means you couldn't create such a class with C# coding directly, so there doesn't need to have any logic to check the programmer hasn't created a matching class.

Comment: And lambdas (especially closures). Even what was compiled into a static delegate in C# 5 is now a singleton instance variable of a class named `<>c` in Roslyn (for performance reasons as instance-bound delegates are faster to call in the CLI).

Comment: What would happen if someone were to declare another class with the same name?  Would the compiler just find another name?

Comment: @Namfuak how? As I said, the names are deliberately chosen to be names that are valid .NET names but not valid C# names. You can't call a C# class something that begins with `<`.

Comment: @JonHanna Ah, I mistook what you said, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 7):

These are the [CompilerGeneratedAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilergeneratedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Distinguishes a compiler-generated element from a user-generated
>   element. This class cannot be inherited.

You can check it like

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;


bool CompilerGen(Type t)
{
    var attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(t, typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute));
    return attr != null;
}
```