# Assembly.GetTypes() also gets methods?

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to unit test a data access layer where each entity is expected to implement an interface that includes Save() and Delete() methods.  I would like to loop through each entity model and perform various tests, which seems simple enough using reflection:

```
[TestMethod]
public void AllDalModelsImplementIMyDALObject()
{
    Assembly dalAssm = typeof(MyDAL.DataModels.MyEntity1).Assembly;
    foreach (Type t in dalAssm.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == "MyDAL.DataModels").ToList())
    {
        // Do stuff here
        TestContext.WriteLine(t.Name + " " + t.Namespace);
    }
}
```

But when I look at the output, in addition to all of the things that seem like `Types` that "are classes", I am also seeing debug lines written for each implementation of my Save and Delete methods:

```
TestContext Messages:
MyEntity1 MyDAL.DataModels
MyEntity2 MyDAL.DataModels
MyEntity3 MyDAL.DataModels
MyEntity4 MyDAL.DataModels
<Save>d__8 MyDAL.DataModels   // what are these and how do I filter them out?
<Delete>d__9 MyDAL.DataModels
<Delete>d__8 MyDAL.DataModels
<Save>d__9 MyDAL.DataModels
<Save>d__8 MyDAL.DataModels
<Delete>d__9 MyDAL.DataModels
<Save>d__8 MyDAL.DataModels
<Delete>d__9 MyDAL.DataModels
```

So my question is what are these?  Why is GetTypes() returning them, and why isn't `t => t.IsClass` filtering them out?  I could filter them by seeing if the name starts with `<`, but is there a better way?

Comment: You're seeing compiler-generated closure types.

Comment: OK, that terminology helps me find better stuff on Google if nothing else!  Revealing this link with my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697570/assembly-gettypes-returns-strange-type-names-e-g-c  If you want to convert this to an answer, I can credit you...  Thanks @SLaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are compiler-generated closure classes, which come from iterators, async methods, or lambdas.

You can filter them by checking for the `CompilerGeneratedAttribute`.