# Weird input name generated by CheckBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

The issue is that for some bizarre reason, when I use CheckBoxFor I get a checkbox but the ID has "CS___8__locals1" in it.  No idea where this comes from or why it's happening.

Any ideas?  See below:

```
<input class="checkbox" id="ProductPlans_0__CS___8__locals1_plans_4__IsSelected" name="ProductPlans[0].CS$&lt;>8__locals1.plans[4].IsSelected" type="checkbox" value="true" />
```

---

My model is a single object (it is in reality part of a collection of objects but that should not matter.  Here is my editor template (leaving out the @model declaration):

```
<tr> 
  <td>
    <label class="checkbox">
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.IsSelected, new { @class = "checkbox" })
      <strong>@Model.MarketingLabel</strong>     
      @Html.Raw(@Model.DisplayName)
    </label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span data-planid="@Model.Id">@Model.Premium.ToString("C")</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="@Model.SBCUrl">Explain</a>
  </td>
  @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Id)
</tr>
```

Comment: Is it a problem? It looks like an compiler-autogenerated name (similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2508828/1364007)) to me.

Comment: Yes it's a problem - when I post the input back to my web server the bindings don't work.  Server expects ProductPlans_0__plans_4__IsSelected for example.

Comment: can you post how is your model? and how are you building the CheckBoxFor ?

Comment: The model binding uses the `name` attribute of your input field. The `id` attribute is completely irrelevant. It's never sent to the server and it never participates to any binding.

Comment: look this link 
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2890

Comment: Wow @DanielGpeReyes how did you find that??!  Thanks!  Doesn't look like there's a resolution but nice to know I'm not losing my mind.

Comment: @Barry  just google "CS___8__locals1", maybe is the way how you're building the collection?

Answer (score 8):

I know this is and old post but maybe will help someone else out there.
So, in my case I had this same problem and the problem was solved after a few try and error and we discover that the error was in itself the for loop.

Our model was something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < PatiosCobro.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-group input-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => PatiosCobro[i].Valor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => PatiosCobro[i].CobroId)
            @Html.NameFor(model => PatiosCobro[i].Valor) 
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This will throw "CS___8__locals1_ETC"

What worked for us was taking out the local variable i and declaring it out in other place.

by example:

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < PatiosCobro.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-group input-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => PatiosCobro[i].Valor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => PatiosCobro[i].CobroId)
            @Html.NameFor(model => PatiosCobro[i].Valor) 
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: This is supposedly a bug fixed in MVC 6: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2890

I also get the issue just by assigning a child of my view model to a variable. `@var alias = Model.InnerVM; @Html.HiddenFor(m => alias.Prop)` generates a hidden named `CS$<>8__locals1.alias.Prop`