# How to read/interpret a raw C# stack trace correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, uwp, .net-native

I'm reading some crash reports from a UWP application (C#, compiled with .NET Native) and I'm having a hard time understanding the exact syntax/format used in the stack traces.
I tried looking for some guides on the internet but I didn't come up with anything useful.

Here are a few examples:

**1)**

```
MyProject.ViewModels.SomeViewModel.<OnLogin>d__69.MoveNext()
```

- `OnLogin` is the name of a method in `SomeViewModel`, so why is it inside angular brackets? Is the `"ClassName".<"MethodName>..."` the usual way to indicate an instance method?
- I understand that the C# compiler turns every chunk of code between `await` calls into anonymous methods and schedules them using continuations, so I guess that `d__69` indicates an async continuation inside the current method.

  - What does the 'd' stand for?
  - Are those numbers random? I mean, the method doesn't have 69 `await` calls, so I guess those numbers aren't sequential. Is it possible to find out the exact part in the original method from that number in the stack trace?
- What is that `MoveNext()` method at the end? What kind of type is it called upon?

---

**2)**

```
MyProject.UserControls.SomeControl.<.ctor>b__0_0
```

- I know that `.ctor` stands for the object constructor, and looking at the code I found out that `b__0_0` stands for an anonymous event handler added inside the constructor, like this: `SomeEvent += (s, e) => Foo();`.

  - What does the 'b' stand for?
  - Why are there two numbers with an underscore? Which one of them refers to the anonymous method index? I mean, it's the first one (so its index is 0) but there are two 0s here. If it was the second, would I have had `0_1`, `1_0` or something else?

---

**3)** I have this method:

```
// Returns a Task that immediately throws when awaited, as soon as the token is cancelled
public static Task<T> GetWatchedTask<T>(this Task<T> awaitableTask, CancellationToken token)
{
    return awaitableTask.ContinueWith(task => task.GetAwaiter().GetResult(), token);
}
```

And I have this stack trace:

```
MyProject.Helpers.Extensions.TasksExtensions.<>c__3$1<System.__Canon>.<GetWatchedTask>b__3_0($Task$1<__Canon> task)
```

- Why doesn't the second parameter (the token) show up in the signature?
- Why is the type `$Task$1` written with the '$' character? Is it like some sort of placeholder/ground indicator (like in a regex) so that it can be used in other places too? (I mean, I see that `$1<System.__Canon>` in what I guess is the method return type)

  - If that first part is the method return type, why isn't it there for all the methods that have a return type? I have lots of stack traces with method that do return a value, but they don't have that same signature.
- What does all that `.<>c__3$1<System.__Canon>` mean? From the `$1` and on I guess that'd be the `Task<T>` return type, but what's that `b__3_0` part, since I don't have async calls or event handlers? Does that mean something different in this case?

---

**4)**

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush..ctor($Color color)
```

- Why does the parameter type start with the '$' character? What does it stand for?

---

**5)** I have this other method:

```
public static async Task<ObservableCollection<SomeCustomClass>> LoadItemGroups(String parentId)
```

And this stack trace:

```
MyProject.SQLiteDatabase.SQLiteManager.<>c__DisplayClass142_3.<LoadGroups>b__3()
```

- What's that `c__DisplayClass142_3`? Is that a way to indicate the return type with a single type rather than the three separate classes (Task, ObservableCollection, SomeCustomClass)?
- Again, why do I have `b__3` here, where in other stack traces it used the format `d_xxx` to indicate an async code chunk?

Sorry for the many questions, I hope this post will help other UWP C# programmers too.

Thank you in advance for your help!

**EDIT**: this question should *not* be considered a duplicate of [this other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508828/where-to-learn-about-vs-debugger-magic-names) because:

- It presents different cases (constructor methods, generic types syntax etc..) instead of just asking for the meaning of some default keywords/symbols related to a certain type of variables
- It specifically asks how to compare a given stack trace to an original method signature, and the steps to do in order to achieve that
- It presents different examples in different contexts, instead of just asking a general question
- And by the way, how can "VS debugger magic names" even be considered a proper question title? How was another user supposed to find that question when looking for C# stack traces symbols meaning?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I bet Eric Lippert will come later and give a better answer, but in case that won't happen - here is my take, because I also got interested in this. The meaning of "d", "c" and similar symbols I got from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2509524/5311735) answer by Eric Lippert.

1) `MyProject.ViewModels.SomeViewModel.<OnLogin>d__69.MoveNext()`

This one is relatively simple. `OnLogin` is async method, and such methods are rewritten by compiler into a state machine. This state machine implements `IAsyncStateMachine` interface which has `MoveNext` method. So your async method basically becomes a sequence of `MoveNext` invocations of that state machine. That is why you see `MoveNext()` in stack trace.

`MyProject.ViewModels.SomeViewModel.<OnLogin>d__69` is the name of generated state machine class. Because this state machine is related to `OnLogin` method - it becomes part of type name. `d` is "iterator class" by the link above. Note that information from link above is 7 years old and is before async\await implementation, but I guess that state machine is similar to iterator (the same `MoveNext` method, same principle) - so "iterator class" looks fine. 69 is some unique number \ counter. I guess it's just counter, because if I compile dll with just two async methods - their state machines would be `d__0` and `d__1`. It's not possible to deduce which part of async method has thrown based on this info.

2) `b` is "anonymous method" (link above). I made some experiments and I think first index is related to the method in which anonymous method was used, and second index seems to be related to index of anonymous method inside that method in which they are used. For example suppose you use 2 anonymous methods in constructor and 2 anonymous methods in method `Foo` in the same class. Then:

```
public Test() {
    Handler += (s, e) => Foo(); // this will be `b__0_0` because it's first in this method
    Handler += (s, e) => Bar(); // this will be `b__0_1` because it's second
}

static void Foo() {
    Action a = () => Console.WriteLine("test"); // this is `b__1_0`, 1 refers to it being in another method, not in constructor. 
    // if we use anonymous method in `Bar()` - it will have this index 2
    a();
    Action b = () => Console.WriteLine("test2"); // this is `b__1_1`
    b();
}
```

3) This looks quite complicated. First you ask "Why doesn't the second parameter (the token) show up in the signature". That's simple - because method in question represents anonymous method `task => task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, not your `GetWatchedTask` method. Now I was not able to reproduce your stack trace with this one, but still some info. First, `System.__Canon` is:

> Internal methodtable used to instantiate the "canonical"
>   methodtable for generic instantiations.
>    The name "__Canon" will never been seen by users but it will appear a lot in debugger stack traces
>    involving generics so it is kept deliberately short as to avoid being a nuisance.

Looks cryptic for me, but I guess it kind of represents your `T` in runtime. Then, `<>c__3$1<System.__Canon>` is `<>c__3$1<T>` and is a name of compiler generated class, where "c" is "anonymous method closure class" (from the link above). Such class is generated by compiler when you create a closure, so capture some external state in your anonymous method. What has been captured should be stored somewhere, and it is stored in such class.

Going futher, `<GetWatchedTask>b__3_0` is a method in that anonymous class above. It represents your `task => task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` method. Everything from point 2 applies here as well.

I don't know the meaning of `$`, maybe it represents number of type parameters. So maybe `Task$1<System.__Canon>` means `Task<T>` and something like `Tuple$2<System.__Canon` would mean `Tuple<T1, T2>`.

4) That I unfortunately don't know and was not able to reproduce.

5) `c__DisplayClass142_3` is again closure class (see point 3). `<LoadGroups>b__3()` is anonymous method you used in method `LoadGroups`. So that indicates some anonymous method which is closure (captured external state) and which was called in `LoadGroups` method.

Comment: Thanks man, looks like a great answer to me! Still looking forward to another answer by Eric Lippert too, as it could add some more details for sure.

Comment: @Sergio0694 hopefully you know at least can find out what exactly method is mentioned in stack trace. By the way, do you have a code to reproduce those $ signs in stacktrace? Especially in your 4-th point.