# C# MVC Javascript Bundling Error, How To Check Javascript Syntax Error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

So I was modifying my javascript files. Before the modification, it can be bundled just fine, but after the modification, the bundling fails.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
> Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.FunctionObject.SafeIsReferenced(HashSet`1 visited) +70 Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.FunctionObject.SafeIsReferenced(HashSet`1 visited) +295
> Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSVariableField.get_IsReferenced() +60
> Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.ActivationObject.AnalyzeNonGlobalScope() +92
> Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.ActivationObject.AnalyzeScope() +33
> Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.GlobalScope.AnalyzeScope() +83
> Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.InternalParse() +1819
> Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.Parse(DocumentContext sourceContext) +74
> Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Minifier.MinifyJavaScript(String source, CodeSettings codeSettings) +592
> System.Web.Optimization.JsMinify.Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response) +91
> System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.ApplyTransforms(BundleContext context, String bundleContent, IEnumerable`1 bundleFiles) +273 System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GenerateBundleResponse(BundleContext context) +141 System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GetBundleResponse(BundleContext context) +45 System.Web.Optimization.BundleResolver.GetBundleContents(String virtualPath) +166 System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.DeterminePathsToRender(IEnumerable`1 assets) +205
> System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.RenderExplicit(String tagFormat, String[] paths) +35
> System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.RenderFormat(String tagFormat, String[] paths) +105
> System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render(String[] paths) +21
> ASP._Page_Views_Home_Customize_cshtml.b__3_1() in C:\Users\astef\Documents\Projects\C#\Yountrep\Yountrep\Yountrep\Views\Home\Customize.cshtml:429
> System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass42_0.b__0(TextWriter tw) +316
> System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +10
> System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +80
> ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in C:\Users\astef\Documents\Projects\C#\Yountrep\Yountrep\Yountrep\Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml:134
> System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
> System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105
> System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +90
> System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.b__0(TextWriter writer) +232
> System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +10
> System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +80
> System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +63 System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +237 System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +98 System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +235 System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107 System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.b__4() +198
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
> System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
> System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
> System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
> System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9836613
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

I am sure that this is caused by a syntax error in my javascript. The problem is that I cannot find the error, the javascript file has more than 1000 lines of code, and it show that it is fine in my visual studio (no syntax error).

How can I find this error? Is there any other tools I can use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read/interpret a raw C# stack trace correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017481/how-to-read-interpret-a-raw-c-sharp-stack-trace-correctly)

Comment: I dont know which line of code in my javascript causes the error, this stacktrace does not give me the information

Answer (score 0):

Bundling and minification does not support `async function()` which I have in my code. So i just change my async function into `function().then();`