# Find out what local variable requires this suppression

Tags: c#, error-suppression

The c# project I am working with has "Warnings as Errors" turned on and they have lots of suppressions in the code. Among them the following:

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage(
"Microsoft.Maintainability"
, "CA1500:VariableNamesShouldNotMatchFieldNames"
, MessageId = "CS$<>8__locals1")]
```

If I remove the suppression, the build fails. How can I find out which specific identifier in the c# code causes the warning?

Comment: `VariableNamesShouldNotMatchFieldNames`, shouldn't it be just as easy as CTRL+F the field name?

Comment: When your build fails, do you get an error message? What does it say? Does it point to a location in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you can't. See that the `MessageId` value is `"CS$<>8__locals1"` - that's a C# compiler-generated local, so you won't see it in the C# source code directly - you'll have to use a tool like ILSpy or Reflector to see the CIL and the variable. [According to this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508828/where-to-learn-about-vs-debugger-magic-names), the `locals` name means it's the name for a closure class variable - which means you're using a lambda function somewhere.

However it should not be necessary to manually suppress this because FxCop is smart enough to know about C#-compiler generated locals and fields (fields or their enclosing types would be annotated with `[CompilerGenerated]` anyway). I'm guessing that your build process is using a recent C# compiler but a very old version of FxCop that does not recognise new C# language features.

Comment: This is not related to FxCop. And none of these are mine.

Comment: @ajeh "FxCop" is the original name for Microsoft's .NET static analysis tool which is now built-in to Visual Studio.